# seam redirect page

Tags: redirect, action, seam, server-side

I use seam to manage a viewer page.
In my page I have a div (iframe) where an html page is displayed on particular conditions.
In particular I need to change the page displayed in this div deciding from serverside.
I try to explain me better:
on commandButton click the control is passed to server (using an action). This action method set some things and know what page should be loaded after (or none in some cases).
when the control come back to the caller page, the new page setted by the action method must be called (it uses the things specified by the action method).

How can I do this?

NOTE: the oncomplete tag is not usable in this context because I have many commandButton and it is called everytime I click on one of the commandButtons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using javascript activated only when a particular property is present over the serverside.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what your trying to do.

Are these pages rendered dynamically?

You can generate HTML from the serversite and just output it using a `<h:outputText id="iframediv" value="#{controller.htmlparameter}" escape="false" />`

An `<a4j:commandButton reRender="iframediv">` could then reRender this dynamically generated page.

If the pages are defined statically you could include them like this.

```
<rich:panel id="iframediv"> 
     <a4j:outputPanel rendered="{controller.page1}">
           <ui:include src="page1.xhtml" />
     </a4j:outputPanel>
     <a4j:outputPanel rendered="{controller.page2}">
           <ui:include src="page2.xhtml" />
     </a4j:outputPanel>
</rich:panel>
```

The controller's page1 and page2 parameters should be booleans and set by the action you've called.

Comment: Thank for the answer and sorry for my english. I understand not explained my problem in a better way.  My serverside action set some things to a DB. On come back to the main page something should appens. First of all read the properties from DB and, if setted, a new page must be called and rendered in a iframe. This "new page" could be a seam page, so all the seam-jstl-authomation must be applied and must go ok (the new page is an xhtml page). Hope this could be more clear.